# Two column article not adjusting with landscape table

Tags: two-column, landscape, afterpage

I have a two-column article with a landscape table. Below is a working example of the article.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}

\section{Heading}
\lipsum[1-8]

\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
        \caption{ Some Caption.} 
        \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}}
            \hline
            Title & Bond & Mission & MIB & Jonny & Nemo & Disney & Princess & Romoe & Juliet & Rocky \\ 
            \hline
            Author &  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 &  9 & 10\\
            Writer & Woody Allen & Woody Allen & Yes & Woody Allen & Woody Allen & Woody Allen & Woody Allen & Yes & Woody Allen & Yes\\
            Actor &  Smart & Smart & Smart & Smart & Smart &  Smart &  Smart & Smart & Smart & Smart \\
            Actress   & No & Bambi& Bambi & Bambi & NO & Women & Women & Women & Women & Women \\
            Director & HA,FA & NO & Women & Women & Women & Women& Women & Women & Women & Women\\
            Genre & Action & Action & Romance & Comedy & Comedy & Comedy & Comedy & Comedy & Romance & Romance  \\
            Oscar &  Yes & Yes & No & No & Yes & No & No & No & No & No\\
            Budget & No & Yes & 1.5 million & 1.5 million & Yes & 1.5 million & 1.5 million & 1.5 million & 1.5 million & 1.5 million \\
            Release & 2015 & 2014 & N/A & 2014 & 2015 & 2015 & 2015& 2014 & 2015 & 2015 \\
            Running time  & 2 Hours & 2 Hours & 2 Hours & 2 Hours & 2 Hours & 1.5 Hours & 1.5 Hours & 1.5 Hours & 1.5 Hours & 1.5 Hours \\
            International Release & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & No & No & No & No & No &  No\\                  
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
\end{landscape}}

\section{Heading}
\lipsum[1-10]   

\end{document}
```

I have also tried to use `afterpage` but I am getting the following result.

[image]

As you can see the next column is empty and the rest of the text continues after the table. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `landscape` needs to use `\clearpage` to flip an entire page, you should use `sidewaystable` which just rotates the float (see Ulrike's answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use sidewaystable*:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\section{Heading}
\lipsum[1-8]

    \begin{sidewaystable*}
        \centering
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
        \caption{Some Caption.}
        \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}}
            \hline
            Title & Bond & Mission & MIB & Jonny & Nemo & Disney & Princess & Romoe & Juliet & Rocky \\
            \hline
            Author &  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 &  9 & 10\\
            Writer & No & No & Yes & No & No & No & No & Yes & No & Yes\\
            Actor &  Reactive & Reactive & Reactive / Proactive & Reactive & Reactive &  Reactive &  Reactive & Reactive & Reactive & Reactive \\
            Actress   & No & Yes (partial)& Yes (partial) & Yes (partial) & NO & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
            Director & HA,FA & NO & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes& Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes\\
            Genre & Global & Global & Global / Local & Local & Local & Local & Local & Local & Global / Local & Global / Local  \\
            Oscar &  Long & Long & Moderate & Moderate & Long & Moderate & Moderate & Moderate & Moderate & Moderate\\
            Budget & No & Yes & Limited & Limited & Yes & limited & limited & limited & limited & limited \\
            Release & Not-support & Support & N/A & support & Not-support & Not-support & Not-support& Intra-domain support & Not-support & Not-support \\
            Running time  & Host-based & Host-based & Host-based & Host-based & Host-based & Network-based & Network-based & Network-based & Network-based & Network-based \\
            International Release & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & No & No & No & No & No &  No\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable*}

\section{Heading}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]